# CodeIgniter: How to reload the form when it is a function in the controller?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

**I can't seem to reload the form to see the error_messages**. I have one function called index() and id() this is the method action which get's executed when the form button is pressed. Also I am using Datampper with it. I know it has form validation itself but I prefer codeigniter's form validations.

```
public function save_comments($article_id)
{
    // Create object for comments
    $comments = new Comment_model();

    // Form Inputs & DataMapper Validaiton
    $comments->name = $this->input->post('name');
    $comments->body = $this->input->post('body');
    $comments->article_id = $article_id;

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Message', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //Something to reaload the form ?
    }

    else
    {
        $comments->save();
        redirect('article/id/'. $article_id);
    }

}
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to reload the page to show the errors, why not do something like:

```
public function save_comments($article_id)
{
    // Create object for comments
    $comments = new Comment_model();

    // Form Inputs & DataMapper Validaiton
    $comments->name = $this->input->post('name');
    $comments->body = $this->input->post('body');
    $comments->article_id = $article_id;

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Message', 'required');

    // Check the form has been submitted
    if ($this->input->post('my_submit_button') !== FALSE)
    {
        if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE)
        {
            // Validated OK, so save
            $comments->save();
            redirect('article/id/'. $article_id);
            return;
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('my_form');
}
```

So essentially the form form is always shown. If you submit your form, you check the validation, if it is valid, go ahead and save, then `return` to stop the rest of the function executing, else let the function continue to exectute and show the form again.

Alternatively, just use the following to direct to the current URL:

```
redirect(current_url(), 'refresh');
```

Comment: nope it doesn't work. I submit it empty and it goes to the action function which is this save_comment ... It doesn't show any erros

Comment: If that's the case then something must be wrong with your validation, it should not run `save_comment` unless it passes your validation. Can you try echoing `validation_errors();` instead of redirecting away to check? Did this work correctly with your original code?

Comment: yeap I am echoing vlaidation errors(); in the view and it doesn't work :( It doesn't event want to save now x

Comment: Can you post your view code so we can see your form?

Comment: I got it when I am echoing the erros here  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) and when I press the button it gives me the errors but in this url /save_comment/42 not in the same page, cause I am using different functions and the form action is pointing to save_comment. In the datamapper I can't find a way how to put the form action in one function, cause everytime I enter the view and it tries to submit without even pressing the button. :(